# How does MPI communication work?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, ipc

I am trying to play with parallel computing, and I've started to study the MPI standard.

I tried to find any information about low level implementation, but unfortunately still searching for it.

I am able to understand all this great high level stuff like rank, communicator and other things. It is not hard, but when I try to understand something I always look for low level details in order to get understanding how does it work under the hood.

So could someone explain me what low level protocols are used for communication ? Is it done over the LAN, shared memory, domain sockets or any other communication means ?

I would be grateful for any details, especially for low level.

Comment: It can be done basically any way the library writer deems useful. Shared memory, ethernet, infiniband, whatever you want. And I seriously doubt those details will help understand you anything, because, really, they are not fixed at all. There are simply too many possible ways. The question seems too broad to me. Question on Stackoverflow should be answerable with a specific answer which can be correct or not, not by many answers each bringing some specific low level details.

Comment: I removed the [tag:openmpi] tag. OpenMPI is **not** the same as MPI ([tag:mpi]). It is just one of many specific MPI implementations. If you are only interested in OpenMPI (seems unlikely to me), you can return the tag back.

Comment: I guess you are asking about *"under-the-hood"* details of the MPI runtime itself rather than the API - try Googling *"MPI runtime"* - this may help http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/cluster.pdf